# Can I use the ssh config file with an unknown hostname

Tags: ssh

I'm using a few AWS EC2 instances that do not have elatic IPs. So their public ip address changes often.

Can I still use the ssh config file to setup all the other options for the connection, then specify the ip address on the command line. Or will I have to edit the config file and update the ip address every time?

e.g.

```
Host example
    User theboss
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example
```

then use this to connect

```
ssh example -? 123.123.123.123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the options under a `Host *` group.

```
Host *
    user theboss
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example
Host gandalf
    Hostname shire.example.com
    User bilbo
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/baggins
```

You may have an example with all the options in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Use the `Private DNS` name for the instance in your configuration.  That should be stable even if the IP address changes.

Comment: The hosts all use different keys and users, so I won't be able to configure it that way. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: If you use different keys and users, just create an entry for each.  You can change the target of an host in its stanza.  See edit.